# width and height must be > 0 error when using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap, android-cardview, mpandroidchart

I wanted to use MPAndroidChartLibrary in my application, but I am experiencing problems which I can't solve on my own. I would like to put the chart into the CardView which is stored inside ListView. CardView's xml looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="16dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDateStartTitle"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

When opening the fragment containing these CardViews I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:754)
>               at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.onSizeChanged(Chart.java:2197)

When I set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to some fixed values (eg. 200dp) inside `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart` the chart looks ok and there is no error. How to get rid of this error while having width and height depending on the parent/content?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your chart height does not depend on the height of its parent `LinearLayout`:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

Try this instead:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```

The second set of attributes will allow your `PieChart` to fill all the vertical height available inside the container `LinearLayout` (after accounting for the height of the `TextView` above it).

Comment: Unfortunetaly this does not work either. The same error. I get no error only when I set `layout_heigt` and `layout_width` to some FIXED value, so I suspect that `match_parent` value is taken by the PieChart library before it is set to the real parent value. However I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you use the code I suggested, and in addition, give the outer FrameLayout a fixed height in dp?

Comment: Oh, also, do you get the same error if the width is `match_parent` but the height is a fixed dp value? Or must both be dp values to avoid the problem?

Comment: In both cases you mentioned it works without an error.

Comment: Are either of those acceptable solutions? It makes sense that `wrap_content` in either dimension is not usable by the pie chart - it probably scales  to match its size, so has no 'built-in' height by default. If you want to get fancy, you could put it in a container whose aspect ratio you fix by overriding onMeasure, but that's a lot more work than specifying a fixed dp height.

Comment: I've set a fixed height and it works as I wanted. So thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to attach the saving of file to gallery in onclick of a button. It works perfectly after that. I guess Once the view is fully drawn, the system have correct height and width.